# Request parameters not showing in post route Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm trying to get the parameters values that are sent to my route. But I get `undefined`
My other routes are working perfectly

```
router.post('/add', (request, response) => {
    console.log('In post route: ', request.body)
    response.send(req.body)
})
```

And here is the screenshot of my postman.

[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVZ5N.jpg)

I already tried using bodyparser. Watched different tutorials, but still having the issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Update this line :  response.send(req.body) to response.send(request.body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your code, You have incorrectly entered the variable name

```
router.post('/add', (request, response) => {
    console.log('In post route: ', request.body)
    response.send(request.body)
})
```

Comment: although this was wrong, but there was another mistake too, I was using the `body-parser` at the end of my server file, I just placed it just after my imports and the code started working as expected